# How to impletement Activity indicator in a box in center and inside there is loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I am trying to implement Activity Indicator in my Vue Native App but Unfortunately, I can achieve it coz it's not showing me the Activity Indicator.

This is the code I have tested

```
<AbsoluteLayout height="100%" width="100%">
    <ActivityIndicator class="indicator" :busy="isLoading" :visibility=" isLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>     
    <ActivityIndicator :busy="isLoading" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" :visibility="isLoading? 'visible':'collapse'"></ActivityIndicator>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Just go with GridLayout, do not use AbsoluteLayout for this purpose. If you still have issues, please post complete code or possibly Playground sample.

Comment: Checking your way

Comment: but what if i want like this [Open Image](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/0/5/05b149b3f6242318c819262d30f9c8abb0e8d43f.jpg)

Comment: I guess you are looking for [nativescript-loading-indicator-ssi](https://github.com/simplec-dev/nativescript-loading-indicator) / [nativescript-loading-indicator](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator)

Comment: help me on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777033/can-some-one-try-to-convert-the-code-in-vue)

Answer (score 0):

Check your isLoading variable, maybe it never switch to true

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridLayout rows="500" columns="500">
            <ActivityIndicator row="0" col="0" class="indicator" busy="true" visibility="visible"  horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

But if i make it dynamic it din't work and alway having problem of having the loader to fill the screen while loading but din't work

Answer (score 0):

Just go with GridLayout, do not use AbsoluteLayout for this purpose. If you still have issues, please post complete code or possibly Playground sample.

If you prefer a progress dialog which is displayed more like a modal on top of your content, then use [nativescript-loading-indicator-ssi](https://github.com/simplec-dev/nativescript-loading-indicator) Or [nativescript-loading-indicator](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator)

Comment: open a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777033/can-some-one-try-to-convert-the-code-in-vue)